# Why don't any mobile operating systems save inactive applications's memory to their storage?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-phone

In phones, it seems that it would only bring benefits if background applications were saved to the storage instead of being killed when memory is low. Are there any reasons why this isn't done? I'm also not talking about pagefile if any phones use that.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would slow down systems by paging stuff to disk and then again writing it back - all producing a very sluggish experience -  waste a significant disk space to store the memory, and make restarting apps more difficult.

It also will wear out the NAND faster (typically between 5000 and 100 000).   The typical speed of NAND is 15-60MB/s in Android - which is very slow compared to SSD's and even hard drives, and glacial compared with RAM.